# How to disable jasypt's automatic property decryption for a single component?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, encryption, inject, jasypt

In my spring boot application, I want jasypt to decrypt injected properties in *all components but one*.

I find jasypt automatic encryption/decryption handy, but in my `SecurityConfig` I want to get the encrypted values, and decrypt them later.

How can I disable jasypt decryption for one property or one class?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;// <= this field will contain the decrypted password, but should contain the encrypted password
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround: Write this in your application.properties:

```
password=ENC_X(1234)
```

And replace `ENC_X` to `ENC`, when injecting the property:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("#{'${password}'.replaceFirst('^ENC_X','ENC')}")
    private String password;// <= this field will contain 'ENC(1234)' (unencrypted)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about  not using ENC() and providing bare encrypted text as password?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it would indeed be a possible workaround. Based on your idea I built another workaround, which fits even better for me (see my own answer).

Comment: It's very smart what you did there, although there are a lot of ways to achieve the same target :p